# Diophantine equations and the area of a triangle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

prove that the area of the triangle whose vertices are (0,0), (b,a), and (x,y) is |by-ax|/2.

Now this is suppose to be a number theory problem. Although I can prove this using other means I am not seeing the connection to Diophantine Equations. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. TYIA!

Comment: one thing that comes to mind is the geometry of numbers -- this is half the area of the fundamental parallelogram, and the expression |by-ax| is the determinant of the two spanning vectors... which is the typical way to prove it...

Comment: Yes, I think I see my mistake. Showing that the relationship is true is all I really needed to do. But, I was thinking that Diophantine equations come into play in the process. The book just needed me to establish the relationship.

Comment: @ rofg1 Thanks!